# How to make a smooth move in iPhone with Unity?

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I just make some cube and let them moved vertically on the build, then I found it was really not smooth on iPhone, could any one help me out?

```
void Update () {
    transform.Translate (0, Time.deltaTime * 3, 0); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At very first script of Build (SplashScreen) normally, write

```
void Start(){
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
}
```

Then in your code in `Update` modify code as,

```
void Update () {
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, new Vector3 (0, -16, 0), Time.deltaTime * 3); 
}
```

`-16` is the target value of `Y`, you can change it.

Comment: Many Thx, The coincidence is I found it at the same time you answered it!!

Comment: What we can say, just coincidence :)

Comment: Actually I just turned on my Mac, sorry for late reply :). Sorry for that something I knew but I couldn't reply on time. As a friend :)

Comment: It's a fantastic tip for new and experienced Unity workers!

Comment: @JoeBlow it is an honor for me that a senior guy like you made a compliment :)

Comment: I am not senior - just old!  But again thanks!  :)  Don't forget the unity3d "answers" site, it is a bit messy but it remains incredibly popular ... http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/267076/view.html ... you can often get better answers there more quickly.

Comment: Senior anyhow :D. And I know Unity Answers Site, I will start some blogs stuff soon, so you guys will help me out. OK sir?

Answer (score 1):

At last, I found where the problem was, that because Unity had limit framerate at 30, it run smoothly after I setting it again.

```
Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
```